# Facebook Auth Dialog Is Different

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I've been strugling with this for hours, no solutions.

I have two apps, both are in sandbox mode with same settings, except categories (getting into that), including advanced settings, served from the same server, using same PHP SDK version, even using same login script.

The problem is, the auth dialog are different for both apps. In one the full enhanced dialog appears (Flops), the other (Dummy App) simply asks for read and write permissions in different screens and in a small box with no application information whatsoever.

Now, about categories. The first app (Dummy App) is a news style app so category is set to News, and the second is a game. When I select game for the dummy app, the dialog appears as I want it to be, like second one (Flops). But this is not a solution and cannot be accepted.

Does anybody have a solution for this mad problem? These I tried with no success:

- I've changed the apps both to sandbox, and live.
- Changing the request code completely.
- Changing permissions so two become same.
- Adding canvas => 1 for requests, and any other setting that getLoginUrl can have

Here is the screenshot of the first app
[image: this is wrong]

The second is like this (the one I want to see in the first app)
[image: aah perfect]

If it can be achieved via code, the current code is like this in both apps:

```
  // Load Facebook sdk
  include_once ROOT . "/facebooksdk/facebook.php";
  $config = array (
    'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'fileUpload' => true
  );
  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

  // Request Facebook user
  $facebookid = $facebook->getUser();

  // Facebook returned signed request
  if ( isset($_POST["signed_request"]) ) {
    // $request = sanitize_string($_POST["signed_request"]);
    // $signedRequest = parse_signed_request($request, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
  }

  // User is missing, send user to permissions page
  if ( !$facebookid ) {
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array ( 'scope' => FACEBOOK_APP_PERMISSIONS ));
    echo "<html><script>top.location.href='{$url}'</script><body>1</body></html>";
    exit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications categorized as games in Facebook get a different OAuth dialog. This is not under your control.

Comment: This feels like a punishment. Today I found out that most of the apps I'm currently using is showing the okay/cancel dialog, which looks like an error message. This will definitely drop the daily new users count.

Comment: Virtually every app uses that new dialog. Facebook heavily A/B tests these things - chances are it converts better. Don't be certain your gut feeling is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply by the way. Accepting this as the right answer.